# AngularJS: Custom Providers, undefined functions?

Tags: angularjs

I have a provider like so:

```
    angular.module('myApp').provider('test', function(){
    this.$get = function($http){
        return {
            test2: function(){
            }
        }
    };

});
```

I then use the provider in my app.config:

```
app.config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, testProvider){
    testProvider.test2();
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider.state('home', {url: '/home', templateUrl: 'template/guide.html'})
    .state('cost', {url:'/cost', templateUrl:'template/cost.html'})
});
```

Im trying to use a provider to get all my pages from a database and return them to the stateProvider... (Which I cant do in app.config because I cant inject the $http service)

This is the error I'm getting:

> Failed to instantiate module myApp due to: TypeError: undefined is
>   not a function

Comment: We may need a bit more code, app refers to angular.module('myApp') i assume?... I have often run into strange errors if I within the same module, try to config a provider before it is loaded... Not sure that is a bug, it was not what I expected anyways, as I would have expected lazy evaluation... But try to create a plunkr...

Comment: Here we are: http://plnkr.co/edit/66ybHvtz4vUyWgmbdALI . Thanks for the insight! (Im not sure if the plnkr has imported Angular properly as Im getting errors in the console)

Comment: Arh, I see your comment in there, you should probably include that in your question... But what your trying to do won't work... your test2() method is not defined on your provider, but rather the service it provides... Think of providers as "Service Factories" that allow you to configure something about a service before it is instantiated...

Comment: In https://github.com/dotJEM/angular-routing we have an "Experimental" api that provides a way to do what your trying to do... see: https://github.com/dotJEM/angular-routing/issues/19 for details. I am not sure what ui-router has to do the same.

Comment: This looks encouraging! Thanks. Il give it a shot and let you know how it goes, looks awesome.

Comment: Agh! Im so happy! Jens, from what you have said, this looks like youre a part of that project. Seriously, a huge well done to the whole team for your efforts. Absolutely fantastic. It works a little too good to be true, its a bit surreal having it "just work" like that.

Comment: I hate to spam up the comments but it wont let me edit my last comment. I am having some issues getting it to work (although I am half way there!) so if youd have the time to look at my latest question, that would mean a lot.

Comment: The other question for referece: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193503/dotjem-angularjs-routing-error-could-not-locate-pagename-under-root

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error, because yu are trying to call `test2()` on the provider (`TestProvider`).
`test2()` is not a method of the provider, but of the provided service (and thus is only accessible at "runtime", not during `config`).

---

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, here is a possible approach:

1. Create a `DelayedRoutes` service (using `provider()`), which has a method for fetching the routes from the server and then registering them with the routing module (be it `ngRoute` or `ui.router` or whatever).
2. This `configRoutes()` methods needs to be invoked at runtime (so it has access to `$http` etc).
   It also needs access to the routing module's provider (e.g. `$routeProvider`, `$stateProvider` etc), which are only available during the configuration time.
3. Your provider will have a method (`setRouteProvider()`), which get's executed during config and stores the `$whateverProvider` for later use (i.e. when the `configRoutes()` gets executed at runtime).

---

Here is a sample implementation (using `ngRoute` for simplicity). You can modify it according to your needs:

```
app.provider('DelayedRoutes', function () {
  var routeProvider;

  // This will be called during `config`
  this.setRouteProvider = function (rp) {
    routeProvider = rp;
  };

  // This will return the actual service
  this.$get = function ($http, $route) {

    // This will be called at runtime, to fetch the routes 
    // from the server and configure client-side routing
    function configRoutes() {
      return $http.get('/gimme/ma/routes').then(
        function onResponse(response) {
          var routes = response.data.routes;

          angular.forEach(routes, function (config, path) {
            if (path === 'otherwise') {
              routeProvider.otherwise(config);
            } else {
              routeProvider.when(path, config);
            }
          });

          $route.reload();
        },
        function onError(error) {
          // Handle the error...
        }
      );
    }

    return {
      configRoutes: configRoutes
    };
  };
});

// During `config`, store `$routeProvider` for later use
app.config(function ($routeProvider, DelayedRoutesProvider) {
  DelayedRoutesProvider.setRouteProvider($routeProvider);
});

// At runtime, config the routes
app.run(function (DelayedRoutes) {
  DelayedRoutes.configRoutes();
});
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/3b3qjh6p/)**.

Comment: I have tried that by returning $http, still had the same problem. Mind giving an example? Thanks!

Comment: The way he defines the provider, the function it self will be the provider, hence it has a $get method. I have written many providers following that pattern.

Comment: @Chizbang: I know you probably found a different approach using Jens' module, but I updated my answer if yoou want to take a look.

Comment: @Jens: Yes, you are right. I was in a hurry and "misread" the code. I have updated the answer. Thx for the heads-up :)